# How to get RFID scanner to connect to MacOS

Tags: macos, usb, hardware

I am using a RFID scanner: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1857525758.html

This scanner connects via USB to Windows and Rasbian without special firmware. When I plug it into my Mac, however, it lights up, but does not scan RFID tags.

It is detected in the system information, which displays:

```
IC Reader:

  Product ID:   0x0035
  Vendor ID:    0xffff
  Version:  1.00
  Serial Number:    08FF20171101
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: IC Reader
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 28
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    200
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Because MacOS is Unix-based, I assumed it work the same on the system. Does anyone know how to get the RFID scanner to connect to my Mac?

Comment: When you connect by USB > Open Finder, does this device appear in the menu?

Comment: No, it does not appear on the side of the finder menu.

Comment: It is clearly written that it supports only Windows. So I doubt it works but have you try to look for a software that you can install for such driver in macOS.

Answer (score 3):

I have a scanner that looks exactly the same and works perfectly on Mac.

Essentially this device works like a USB keyboard, and thus requires no special operating system or driver support.

The device is NOT supposed to show up in The Finder sidebar, contrary to other suggestions here.

To test the device, open Notes, TextEdit or similar app - then scan a tag with the scanner. The number should show up (make sure you can enter numbers with your normal keyboard - i.e. a text input area needs to be in focus).

If it doesn’t work it can be an issue with the port, cable or similar. Check System Report to see if the device is reported as connected on the USB bus.

Update: After you have added the USB information from System Report to your question, it is clear that the hardware you have is a non-standards compliant "China clone" (for example the vendor code is 0xffff), which does seem to be USB HID, but not emulating a keyboard.

In this case, you will need a driver. It seems multiple people have had problems getting this device working on Linux, and someone used a lot of time reverse engineering the Windows program supplied with the device, as the manufacturer is obviously not interested. You can download the Linux software here:

https://github.com/merbanan/rfid_app
https://github.com/Simpleyyt/libfunction_so_usb

It uses libusb so it can probably be compiled and works on a Mac as well. I haven't tried though, as I haven't got the exact device you have.

Comment: The cable I am using is not broken, as it works perfectly on other operating systems. The device does not show any output when connected to mac in TextEdit. The system report, however, does show the scanner.

Comment: And what does system report say about the scanner? Please add screenshot or the text.

Comment: Note that some devices have multiple “modes” available over USB. Some for example can act as a CDC serial device. Usually there’s a button or a command that allow switching between modes. For more information, consult the manual that came with if - or link to the manufacturer.

Comment: I have updated the question with the system report. The device does not have a switch, or any buttons for that matter.